Package warning
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/vctrs_0.6.5.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1336614 bytes (1.3 MB)
downloaded 1.3 MB
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/dplyr_1.1.4.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1560509 bytes (1.5 MB)
downloaded 1.5 MB
package ‘vctrs’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘dplyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning: package ‘dplyr’ was built under R version 4.3.3
Attaching package: ‘dplyr
How can I solve this?
I tried to load the packages
#Load the packages
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)

It gives me this warning:

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\local user\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpgRQJGu\downloaded_packages
> install.packages("dplyr")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
also installing the dependency ‘vctrs’



The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\local user\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpgRQJGu\downloaded_packages
> library(leaflet)
Warning: package ‘leaflet’ was built under R version 4.3.3Registered S3 method overwritten by 'htmlwidgets':
  method           from         
  print.htmlwidget tools:rstudio
> library(dplyr)
Warning: package ‘dplyr’ was built under R version 4.3.3


I'm guessing you're using a version of R that is earlier than 4.3.3.  In which case either (a) update your version of R to V4.3.3 or later or (b) install an earlier version of dplyr from the archive.

A warning is just that, a warning, you do not necessarily require to solve it, unless what it says directly affects your work. If both packages were loaded correctly, albeit with warnings, you can ignore the warnings.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It's just a warning that your version of R is earlier than that which that version of dplyr was built in - it can generally be ignored unless you run into issues with that package.
Check your version of R by running version. In my experience, as long as the version of R isn't too far out you shouldn't run into problems. If you're running something much older (e.g. 3.x, 4.0.x or even 4.1.x) it's probably worth updating.
